# SOAP UI Groovy JsonNull Handling

Tags: groovy, soapui

Hello I'm new to this Groovy Script thing in SOAP UI can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong? i can't do a if null condition with this code

```
//Getting Request
def RequestMessage=context.request
log.info RequestMessage
def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(RequestMessage)

try{
    if(jsonSlurper.iso8583Request.iso8583Detail.bit127){
        log.info "127 is null"
    }else{
        testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("revBit127", "${jsonSlurper.iso8583Request.iso8583Detail.bit127}")
}catch{
    log.info "127 is null"
}
```

Any advice to handle if null condition from this Json object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not far off.

Firstly, I don't chain when using JSON Slurper, I tend to use it like this...

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;

def response = context.expand( '${SOME REST Request#Response#$[\'message\']}' )

// Create a slurper object.
def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper();

// Create the JSON
def json = slurper.parseText(response);
```

In your example, I think this is wrong...

```
if(jsonSlurper.iso8583Request.iso8583Detail.bit127){
    log.info "127 is null"
```

You're actually checking it exists, instead try...

```
if(!jsonSlurper.iso8583Request.iso8583Detail.bit127){
    log.info "127 is null"
}else{
    testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("revBit127", "${jsonSlurper.iso8583Request.iso8583Detail.bit127}")
}
```